# Como ordenar o conteúdo de um Array

Tags: php, array, classificação, order

### Tenho a seguinte `Array` com os respectivos dados aplicados:

1. Número do Cartão
2. Mês (*Validade ou Vencimento*)
3. Ano

Recebo esses dados de uma [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/API) externa, porém de forma "desorganizada". Gostaria de tratar esses valores para seguir um **padrão específico**. Tentei utilizar a função `sort()` do [php](/questions/tagged/php), mas sem sucesso.

Recebo-os desta forma (desordenada/aleatoriamente)

```
Array                                                                                                
(
    [0] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 2020
        [2] => 09
    )

    [1] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 09
        [1] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [2] => 2020
    )

    [2] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 9
    )                                                                                                    
)
```

### Nota-se que ...

os valores das chaves **[0]**, **[1]** e **[2]** são diferentes em relação aos demais **elementos**. O que era pra ser:

- **[0]** = Número do Cartão
- **[1]** = Mês
- **[2]** = Ano

Portanto, gostaria de criar/usar uma função na qual fosse possível padronizá-los desta forma:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 09
        [2] => 2020
    )

    [1] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 09
        [2] => 2020
    )

    [2] => Array 
    (
        [0] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 20
    )
)
```

<sup>independente de suas posições...</sup>

---

#### Vale ressaltar também

Que, de acordo com este cenário, onde o ano de **2020** é mostrado com apenas 2 casas decimais, ou seja, **20** haveria um conflito com os valores do **Mês**, mas tratando-se de validade, para obter o Mês sem saber sua posição (*além de recebe-los de forma desordenada..*)

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
    (
        ["mes"] => 09
        ["cartao"] => 5522 8600 0000 0000
        ["ano"] => 20
    )
)
```

No entanto, por não existir chaves "nomeadas", basta simplesmente criar condições, onde:

- *valor menor ou igual que **12** refere-se ao mês*

seguindo o número de meses que temos em **1** ano. Já

- *valor maior que **12** refere-se ao ano*

Com isso consigo obter os respectivos valores, o contrário do **Número do cartão** que só basta utilizar o [Algoritmo Luhn](https://github.com/maxipago/sdk-card-validation) para validar números de cartão de Crédito/Débito que resolve!

Comment: Isso não pode ocorrer, é um erro grave de projeto que deve ser corrigido no backend visando uma padronização dos dados. É grave pois se buscar um registro do começo do século, por exemplo, surge a possibilidade dos dados serem indistinguíveis.

Comment: Como assim @AugustoVasques ?

Comment: tem que tornar o retorno dessa chamada uniforme. Consertar isso no forntend é gambiarra.

Comment: mas o meu propósito é justamente consertar no back-end, eu recebo esses valores de forma `desordenada` de uma API externa (um outro servidor) e ordena-la para passar para o front-end de forma `ordenada` do meu projeto

Comment: O backend é processo interno. Um dos processos interno desse código php(que não deixa de um processo interno da sua aplicação) é essa API em questão que não é amigável ao desenvolvedor pois não assegura a consistência dos dados pois não apresenta hierarquia e estrutura hegemônica nas respostas as solicitações, o que pode implicar situações onde a informação é indecifrável, o exemplo já citado de buscas por registros datados do inicio do século até 2012. Essa API é quem deve ser corrigida ou substituída.

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendi, a solução deve vir a partir da API né isso? então para obter esses valores de forma ordenada eu precisaria fazer o que necessáriamente? (infelizmente essa é a unica API até então que pode fornecer esses dados..)

Comment: É isso sim. Você pode dizer qual é a API e fornecer um link para documentação da função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno processo para te ajudar, certamente não é a melhor maneira mas pode ser o seu ponto de partida nessa ordenação.

```
    <?php

// Dado o array inicial
$arr = [
    [
        0 => '5522 8600 0000 0000',
        1 => '2020',
        2 => '09'
    ],
    [
        0 => '09',
        1 => '5522 8600 0000 0000',
        2 => '2020'
    ],  
    [
        0 => '5522 8600 0000 0000',
        1 => '20',
        2 => '9'
    ]
];

// Vamos normalizar o tamanho dos elementos para eles poderem ser comparáveis com o min e max mais adiante
$arr_normalizado = [];

foreach($arr as $i)
{
    $arr_normalizado[] = [
        0 => str_pad($i[0], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
        1 => str_pad($i[1], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
        2 => str_pad($i[2], 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)
    ];
}

// Criando o novo array
$arr_new = [];

foreach($arr_normalizado as $i)
{
    // O maior elemento certamente é o número do cartão
    // e o menor elemento ceertamente é o mês (porque já passamos de 2012)
    $ordenado = [
        0 => max($i),
        1 => substr(min($i), -2)        
    ];
    
    // O último elemento que precisamos buscar é o ano
    // como não sabemos em que posição estava no array normalizado
    // é só buscarmos pelo elemento que não é nenhum dos outros dois
    // que já obtemos pelo min e max
    foreach($i as $v)
    {
        if (!in_array($v, $ordenado))
        {
            $ano = (int) $v;
            
            if ($ano < 2000)
            {
                $ano += 2000;
            }
            
            $ordenado[2] = $ano;
        }
    }   
    
    $arr_new[] = $ordenado;
        
}


print_r($arr_new);
```